# Can Axions escape the Black Holes?

Tags: black-hole, general-relativity, axion

I read about Tachyons and Gravitational Waves and also about Exotic matter, really nothing can escape a Black Hole, can [Axions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axion) escape for providing a new hope?

Comment: No. Axions are like neutrinos, but yet more smaller. They are not even massless, like photons. Btw, there is no proof that they would exist.

Comment: There are [some hints](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.09721) for the existence of Axions though and the [XENON Dark Matter Search](http://www.xenon1t.org/) still looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you are inside a black hole, every direction leads towards the singularity.  So for every particle, whether it is massless or not, would travel towards the singularity, and not escape.

Axions have not been proved to exist, but they would also not be able to escape.

Comment: Ok, so an object with 0 Gravity and positive Gravity can't escape a Black Hole but is there any probability that Exotic Matter can escape because it has repulsive Gravity and opposing properties.

Comment: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153376/what-would-happen-if-a-negative-mass-crossed-the-event-horizon-of-a-black-hole The negative mass can't escape, the black hole.

Comment: James, do you know of any astrophysical entity which can escape the Black Hole. Or, there is nothing in our knowledge, that can escape the Black Hole.

Comment: To our best current understanding of black holes (GR) nothing can escape a black hole.  Space inside a black hole is curved so all directions head towards the singularity, so it doesn't matter what direction you go, at what speed and with what special properties a particle might have, you will always move towards the singularity.  It is like "can you escape next wednesday?"  because the only permitted direction in time heads towards next wednesday.  It doesn't matter what happens you are sure to get to next wednesday eventually.

Comment: So, in your opinion, there is no such astrophysical or Quantum object which can escape the Event Horizon of the Black Hole, by our current models, General Theory and Quantum Field Theory

Comment: In a more abstract or philosophical sense, could not the theory of everything escape a black hole?  I mean, it could know what's going on in there, so far as it's in there, and, we might come to know it.  I know that philosophy is out, but, still.